# What are the disadvantages of storing data in a scoped service (per request) to improve performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Service looks like this:

```
public class TestService
{
    private ExternalService _externalService;
    private Dictionary<int, string> _data = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public TestService(ExternalService externalService)
    {
        _externalService = externalService;
    }

    public string GetItem(int id)
    {
        if (_data.TryGetValue(id, out var item))
        {
            return item;
        }

        var result = _externalService.GetItem(id);

        this._data.Add(id, result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And registration:

```
services.AddScoped<TestService>();
```

This service will not be called from multiple threads.

What are the disadvantages of such a solution?
There can be hundreds or thousands of items in the dictionary. mb it can cause some memory issues?

Comment: You are comparing scoped to what? Transient? Singleton?

Comment: Have you considered a `Singleton` with a `MemoryCache` instead?

Comment: `There can be hundreds or thousands of items in the dictionary` So a single web request to your service is going to make _thousands of calls_ to an external service? Umm, that doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: use singleton services if possible. That's what you should follow. In this case even if you cannot use singleton for some reasons that you don't share, we can always use scoped services and have solution to make it fast and less resource-intensive as much as possible, using a dedicated cache server is one big solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

As you write the downside is memory. Another downside is that you can get served dirty values.

I would use a standard cache system, like Redis. Then you can also read about expiry times.

The pattern itself with a cache is what a million other websites use to save roundtrips to different places.